Как вывести на карту множество меток из JSON
Как на карту вывести множество меток из JSON файла? JSON файл будет создаваться из базы данных

Начнёт отсюда [Ask]

Для вывода меток из JSON-файла вы можете сериализировать объекты JSON и пройтись в цикле по каждому. Каждый JSON-объект вы можете распарсить на необходимые поля и использовать полученные данные в выводе меток.
